# Which outcomes to consider in sample space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

Should the sample space of an experiment include all the outcomes irrespective of their order. For example-

***A box contains 1 red and 3 identical white balls. Two balls are drawn at random from the box in succession without replacement.***

The sample space given in the textbook is **WR,RW,WW**
But according to me the sample space should be ***RW1,RW2,RW3,W1R,W2R,W3R,W1W2,
W1W3,W2W3***

How should one decide what to use in which situation as the same book uses my method in many other questions.
For example, another question says-

***A bag contains 9 discs of which 4 are red, 3 are blue and 2 are yellow. All discs are similar in shape and size. A disc is drawn at random from the bag***

The sample space given in the solution is-
***R1,R2,R3,R4,B1,B2,B3,Y1,Y2***

What is the real logic to be used while describing the sample space?

Answer (score 1):

The first experiment has two trials, and each two-letter experiment outcome is meant to express in sequence the two trial outcomes. Since the white balls are identical, your proposed outcomes $RW_1, RW_2$ and $RW_3$ are indistinguishable, so are collectively effectively just the single outcome $RW.$

The second experiment has one trial, and here the exercise apparently considers the four red balls to be non-identical, i.e., $R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4$ to be distinct outcomes.

Comment: That's the problem! How to identify whether to treat them as distinct elements or as same?

Comment: @VarunSingh The first exercise is unambiguous: it explicitly says "identical white balls"; so you are wrong and the book is correct. The second exercise, though, just says the red balls are "similar in size and shape"; this doesn't mean that they are identical; to be honest, there is no clear-cut interpretation here; best to rely on context (in other words, interrogate the entire exercise and ask: "in this scenario, are $R_1,R_2$ really **distinct** outcomes, or are they in fact the **same** outcome?"), and generally assume no more than necessary.

Comment: Thanks...i got the point

Comment: @VarunSingh Orthogonally related, to give you a stronger sense of how we can set up (and the flexibility of) notation in probability modelling: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4038388/21813) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4258513/21813). (The choice of sample space is like the design of a definition: can be somewhat of an art, and depends on the desired level of detail.) Ultimately, just keep making sense of the problem and keeping track of what you're doing.