# Why do some people put elementary events as the arguement of the probability function?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

I'm taking an introductory statistics course for *engineers*, so my
textbook can be a little loose when it comes to formal definitions,
and I have to look certain things up myself.

I know that the probability function is defined as $P: \mathcal{P}(S)
\rightarrow [0,1]$, where $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is the powerset of the
sample space. However, I sometimes see others (namely my professor)
write $P(e)$ where $e \in S$. Are they being sloppy? Did they mean
$P(\{e\})$?

Comment: Yes, they are most likely just being sloppy about the notation. Like you're saying, $P(e)$ doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It isn't too uncommon to lessen the notation regarding probabilities though. When you consider a random variable $X$ you might write $P(X\in A)$, but "$X\in A$" isn't a set in the powerset either, it's just shorthand for
$\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\}$

Comment: This abuse of notation (writing $P(e)$) is in fact much more common than writing the rigorously-correct $P(\{E\}).$ [remark #6](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4038388/21813)